# Subdivision problem during modeling

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm a beginner at Blender. I'm trying to model a wrench, which looks like this without applying the subdivision modifier:[image]

And like this after using the subdivision modifier:[image]

A closer look of the end:
[image]
[image]

There are no doubles and I think I have enough tightening loops here. Really can't figure out what's wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: 1- Avoid Ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices). 2- Use quad based topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender can't figure out what to do with that big, oddly-shaped face on top.  You can see that even with a simple cylinder:

[image]

A few extra cuts on that face will make it smaller and convex, and it solves the problem:

[image]

That said, you should try to avoid large faces with more than 3-5 edges (preferably 4 edged quadrilaterals), which will give you the best results for subdivision.

Also, your initial model is very high-poly for a model you intend to subdivide.  Your UN-subdivided model is high-poly enough that it'd probably already work for most uses.

For subdivision modelling, I always try to economize the amount of quads before subdividing. Here's a quick wrench I did that uses a pretty small number of vertices:

[image]

...but it still subdivides quite nicely:

[image]

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much!!!