# how to fix subsurf modifier deformity

Tags: objects, subdivision-surface

I'm making a gun and one of the parts to it is not subsurf dividing correctly and creates this atrocity is there any way i can fix this? yes, i have tried loopcuts[image]

Comment: See this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142277/subdivision-problem-during-modeling/142281#142281

Comment: Blender will fill faces even where you don't want, so you need to correct your topology as explained by Dale Cieslak in his link